# An Array containing a function in React - [function(page) { return page.menu_order; }]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am wondering what this line does:

```
allPages = _.sortBy(allPages, [function(page) { return page.menu_order; }]);
```

I am wondering especially about the array containing a function

`[function(page) { return page.menu_order; }]`

could someone explain this to me? Will it return an array? How does this work, and what is this technique called? I have never seen this before.

Comment: you can try this code in console in jsbin or even on lodash page

Comment: take a look at docs, they use array, because you can provide mutliple iterator functions. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Comment: Though, I don't think this is related to react